# Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.4/$injector/unpr?p0=%24ngMapProvider%20%3C-%20%24ngMap at Error (native)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui, ng-map

I get following error when I run my application. Just want to know what this means if anyone has experienced with the same?

Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.4/$injector/unpr?p0=%24ngMapProvider%20%3C-%20%24ngMap
    at Error (native)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js:6:416
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js:38:22
    at Object.d [as get] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js:36:49)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js:38:94
    at d (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js:36:49)
    at e (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js:36:310)
    at Object.instantiate (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js:36:451)
    at $get (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js:75:409)
    at http://localhost:11080/angularui/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.min.js:8:29473

NOTE: Code is bit complex to publish here.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to inject/use `ngMapProvider` in a place where it isn't correctly included as a dependency.

See: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr

Comment: Thanks! apparently yes.

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you could accept the answer, then.